# Skipping undefined elements when getting catchment area

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, catchment-area

I have a follow-up question on [Population in upstream area (looping over FeatureCollection)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343516). I want to calculate the number of people living in the upstream area of stations in rivers. This code works in principle:

```
var stations = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/stations');
var hydro = require('users/gena/packages:hydro');
var PopCount2000= ee.Image('CIESIN/GPWv411/GPW_UNWPP-Adjusted_Population_Count/gpw_v4_population_count_adjusted_to_2015_unwpp_country_totals_rev11_2000_30_sec');

var UpstreamPop = stations.map(function(feature){
    var props = ee.Feature(feature).get('GEMS_Stati')

    var geom = ee.Feature(feature).geometry()

    var catchmentsSelected = hydro.getCatchments({outlet: geom, level: 6})

    var union = catchmentsSelected.union(); 

    var catchment_Pop2000 = PopCount2000.reduceRegion({
      geometry: catchmentsSelected,
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    })

    return ee.Feature(null, catchment_Pop2000).set('GEMS_Stati', props)
})

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: UpstreamPop,
  description: 'UpstreamPop',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

However, some of the stations are not inside the defined catchment areas. Therefore, "catchmentSelected" can not be defined. When running the code I get the error message  "Element.get: Parameter 'object' is require". One of the 'problem stations' is for example this one:

```
stations.filter(ee.Filter.eq("GEMS_Stati", 'CHN00009'))
```

How can I run over all stations and skip the stations that are not in the catchment area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before mapping over the stations, you can try to find which stations are in a catchment. Add a property to each station and then filter out the stations not in a catchment.

In Gena's packages, you could have found that you can import all hydro level 6 catchments using the id I provided below. If you have all the catchments, you can apply `filterBounds()` on that featurecollection to make sure all station geometry are within a catchment.

```
// remove first the stations not inside a catchment
var stationsRemoved = stations.map(function(station){
  var catchmentsSelected = ee.FeatureCollection('users/gena/HydroEngine/hybas_lev06_v1c')
                            .filterBounds(station.geometry());

  return station.set('contains', catchmentsSelected.size());
}).filter(ee.Filter.gte('contains', 1));
print(stationsRemoved.size())
print(stations.size())
```

You should then be able to continue with the script you wrote.

[Link GEE script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b4193e4daa046f76eaec7605724db5ff)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, could you accept the answer?