# List of international upstream areas

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, catchment-area

I have a list of stations in rivers. I want Earth Engine to return me a list of stations whose upstream area overlaps with at least one other country in addition to the country the station is in. This is more or less the code for one station in Brazil using the hydro package by gena. The station should be in the list because its upstream area crosses into Colombia and Venzuela. How can I run a code over all stations and return a list with the property 'GEMS_Stati' for stations with an international upstream area?

```
var stations = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/stations');
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var hydro = require('users/gena/packages:hydro');

var filter = ee.Filter.inList('GEMS_Stati', ['BRA00020']);
var FilteredStation = stations.filter(filter);

var catchmentsSelected = hydro.getCatchments({outlet: FilteredStation, level: 6})

var union = catchmentsSelected.union();
Map.addLayer(union);

var spatial_filter = ee.Filter.intersects({
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo',
  maxError: 10
});

var saveAllJoin = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'scenes',
});

var join_output = saveAllJoin.apply(union, countries, spatial_filter);
print(join_output);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Population in upstream area (looping over FeatureCollection)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343516/population-in-upstream-area-looping-over-featurecollection)